# MS CRM 4.0 Remove inactive account from another list

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have the following problem, on which I can't seem to find an answer...
I have a CRM 4.0 system and I want to achieve the following:
When I have a contact/account that's inactive to remove it from another list, for example the Marketing list.

So I already have everything, up to the removing part. I have a collection with the inactive accounts/contacts (The ID's(GUID)), I just need to remove somehow the member from the list. So there is a class  `RemoveMemberListRequest`  which looks like the correct one, the only problem is, somehow I can't get it to work.

```
 foreach (Guid currentMember in inactiveMembers)
            {
                RemoveMemberListRequest req = new RemoveMemberListRequest();
                req.ListId = context.PrimaryEntityId;
                req.EntityId = currentMember ;
                RemoveMemberListResponse rmlResp = (RemoveMemberListResponse)crmService.Execute(req);
            }
```

When It tries to Execute, the request it fails, with very generic error, that it was unable to execute the request. I am also not sure if that's the correct way of doing it...

There is another class that seems to have a property that might be useful:
`QualifyMemberListRequest`

With property: `OverrideorRemove` 
But I don't really understand how this one works, and I couldn't find enough information.

Anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RemoveMemberListRequest` is the correct request.

Pretty much all exceptions thrown by CRM webservice requests are actually of type `SoapException`, and in that case they will **always** say "Server was unable to process request" in the `Message` property, which of course isn't very helpful.

To find out more about the error, you must treat the exception as a `SoapException` and have a look at the `Detail.InnerText` property, which in most cases will provide useful information about what went wrong:

```
try
{
    foreach (Guid currentMember in inactiveMembers)
    {
        RemoveMemberListRequest req = new RemoveMemberListRequest();
        req.ListId = context.PrimaryEntityId;
        req.EntityId = currentMember ;
        RemoveMemberListResponse rmlResp = (RemoveMemberListResponse)crmService.Execute(req);
    }
}
catch (SoapException ex)
{
    string sExceptionDetail = ex.Detail.InnerText;

    // write sExceptionDetail somewhere you can look at it
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // do your normal error handling here
}
```

I guess you either picked up some "wrong" ID somewhere, or it is a roles/privileges issue.

Comment: It looks like you are right (Once again...)
There is something wrong with the ID's I am trying to pass..

Comment: Fixed... that was it indeed... Thanks for the help!